# Error: The method 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter

Every time I try to debug i get this error, Error: The method 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
I have tried lots of method to solve it cant find my way around it.
This is the code. Pls anybody with an ideal of dealing with this problem

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:card_settings/card_settings.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}




class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
String title = "Spheria";
  String author = "Cody Leet";
  String url = "http://www.codyleet.com/spheria";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  static LoginPage of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<LoginPage>();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body:  Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: CardSettings(
          children: <Widget>[
            CardSettingsHeader(label: 'Favorite Book'),
            CardSettingsText(
              label: 'Title',
              initialValue: title,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Title is required.';
              },
              onSaved: (value) => title = value,
            ),
            CardSettingsText(
              label: 'URL',
              initialValue: url,
              validator: (value) {
                if (!value.startsWith('http:')) return 'Must be a valid website.';
              },
              onSaved: (value) => url = value,
            ),
          ],
        ),
    ), 
    );
  }
}
    **Used it in this here
    Pls ignore extra brackets**

    import 'package:domesms/screens/Login.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    final String title ;

    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('DOMESMS.COM')),
          body: Center(child: Text('My Page!')),
          drawer: Drawer(
            // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
            // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
            // space to fit everything.
            child: ListView(
              // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName:  Text('Oludiya Ay`enter code here`odeji'),
                 accountEmail:Text('ayodiya@gmail.com'),
                 currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                   backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/unisexavatar.png',),
                   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                   radius: 80
                 ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent),
              title: Text('ACCOUNT DETAILS'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer

                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()));

              },
            )
```

Comment: Try upgrading your Flutter sdk

Comment: That may be because LoginPage  is not a InheritedWidget and the context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<LoginPage>(); may be for InheritedWidget only. I am just guessing and trying to help.

Comment: Solved by upgrading to the latest flutter. Thanks

Comment: I've tried your code in the current release of Flutter (1.22.4), I've got a different error "Error: Type argument 'LoginPage' doesn't conform to the bound 'InheritedWidget' of the type variable 'T' on 'BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType'."  instead. In your code you've declared `LoginPage` as [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and not an [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). Did I miss something from your code? Or should you create a subclass that extends `InheritedWidget`?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late, but whoever comes through this question, hope this helps.
I faced same issue after upgrading to flutter 2.0,

below steps solved my issue.

to solve error above,

1. open your pubspec.yaml,
2. hit pub upgrade.

let it complete. then run your project again.
error got solved.

[see this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prLh3.png)

Comment: In your case the offending plugin was probably updated. In my case the offending plugin has not been updated since the breaking flutter/dart code was updated.